# How to update an XML node in XSLT with escaped tags (between &lt; and &gt;)

Tags: xslt

```
  <Instance xsi:type="ButtonConfig">
    <Name>ExitButton</Name>
    <LayoutProperties xsi:type="Layout">
      <Rows>
        <Row>
          <Height>100</Height>
        </Row>
      </Rows>
      <Columns>
        <Column>
          <Width>1</Width>
        </Column>
        <Column>
          <Width>610</Width>
        </Column>
        <Column>
          <Width>100</Width>
        </Column>
        <Column>
          <Width>0</Width>
        </Column>
      </Columns>
    </LayoutProperties>
    <ItemXmlAttributes>
      &lt;AllItemsConfig&gt;
        &lt;ItemConfig&gt;
          &lt;ItemName&gt;ItemName1&lt;/ItemName&gt;
          &lt;Interval&gt;200&lt;/Interval&gt;
        &lt;/ItemConfig&gt;
        &lt;ItemConfig&gt;
          &lt;ItemName&gt;ItemName2&lt;/ItemName&gt;
          &lt;Interval&gt;500&lt;/Interval&gt;
        &lt;/ItemConfig&gt;
      &lt;/AllItemsConfig&gt;
    </ItemXmlAttributes>
  </Instance>
```

I have an xml with the above structure. The Instance node is repeated multiple times in the xml file.
I need to make two changes in this xml file:

How do I update the Second column width in the LayoutProperties from 610 to 700 using XSLT?
How do I update the Interval from 500 to 600 for ItemName2 in the ItemXmlAttributes using XSLT?

Comment: What version of XSLT? Can it be XSLT 2.0?

Comment: "*How do I update the Interval from 500 to 600*" Not easily; see the answers given here http://stackoverflow.com/a/23768464/3016153 and here http://stackoverflow.com/a/23788569/3016153

Comment: This is a good example of why you SHOULDN"T try to express XML-structured content as text. If it was actual XML, it would be parsed with the rest of the document and XML tools would be able to process it easily.

Comment: I found a XSLT 1.0 solution that works in Saxon 6.5.5 and Xalan. Try it out.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution with XSLT 1.0 and text concatenation which allows you to extract data from escaped XML. It involves storing the text into a variable and reloading it with the `document()` function. Using a [data URI scheme](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2397) it is possible to load embedded data as if it were an external document with the syntax:

```
data:[<mediatype>],<data>
```

Reading the string contents of the `<ItemXmlAttributes>` tag into a variable, we will have a string containing XML:

```
'<AllItemsConfig><ItemConfig> ... </ItemConfig></AllItemsConfig>'
```

But we can't process it with the templates it since it was loaded as a *string*. It needs somehow to be converted into a *nodeset*.

It can be treated as an embedded document by appending the URI Scheme to the beginning of the string. According to the [XSLT 1.0 Specification 12.1 Multiple Source Documents](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#document) the `document()` function supports this if the processor supports the URI scheme. I tried it with Saxon 6.5.5 and Xalan and it worked. This:

```
document('data:text/xml,<AllItemsConfig><ItemConfig> ... </ItemConfig></AllItemsConfig>')
```

will load the string as a XML document which can be processed with templates.

This template:

```
<xsl:template match="ItemXmlAttributes">
    <xsl:variable name="input">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates 
            select="document(concat('data:text/xml,',$input))/AllItemsConfig" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

will read the text contents of `<ItemXmlAttributes>` and store it in the `$input` variable. Then it will copy that element, and apply the templates of the contents as a parsed XML document.

There is no automatic way to generate the escaped tags. One solution is to print the escaped angle brackets and tag names directly. This is your *escaped identity transform*, for the elements in the escaped portion of the file which are not modified:

```
<xsl:template match="*[ancestor-or-self::AllItemsConfig]">
    <xsl:text>&lt;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
    <xsl:text>&gt;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <xsl:text>&lt;/</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
    <xsl:text>&gt;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

This template selects the `Interval` with an `ItemName` sibling containing "ItemName1", and changes the contents to 600. It prints only text. No tags:

```
<xsl:template match="Interval[../ItemName='ItemName2']">
    <xsl:text>&lt;Interval&gt;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>600</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&lt;/Interval&gt;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

Your other transformations are very simple and most of the processing is done by identity transforms. This one replaces the data in your second column:

```
<xsl:template match="Column[2]">
    <xsl:copy>700</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

And the identity transform copies the other nodes unchanged:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

This is the full stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:preserve-space elements="Interval ItemName ItemConfig AllItemsConfig"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="Column[2]">
        <xsl:copy>700</xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="ItemXmlAttributes">
        <xsl:variable name="input">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates 
                select="document(concat('data:text/xml,',$input))/AllItemsConfig" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="*[ancestor-or-self::AllItemsConfig]">
        <xsl:text>&lt;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
        <xsl:text>&gt;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:text>&lt;/</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
        <xsl:text>&gt;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="Interval[../ItemName='ItemName2']">
        <xsl:text>&lt;Interval&gt;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>600</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>&lt;/Interval&gt;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And this is the result of the transformation:

```
<Instance xmlns:xsi="ns1" xsi:type="ButtonConfig">
   <Name>ExitButton</Name>
   <LayoutProperties xsi:type="Layout">
      <Rows>
         <Row>
            <Height>100</Height>
         </Row>
      </Rows>
      <Columns>
         <Column>
            <Width>1</Width>
         </Column>
         <Column>700</Column>
         <Column>
            <Width>100</Width>
         </Column>
         <Column>
            <Width>0</Width>
         </Column>
      </Columns>
   </LayoutProperties>
   <ItemXmlAttributes>&lt;AllItemsConfig&gt;
        &lt;ItemConfig&gt;
        &lt;ItemName&gt;ItemName1&lt;/ItemName&gt;
        &lt;Interval&gt;200&lt;/Interval&gt;
        &lt;/ItemConfig&gt;
        &lt;ItemConfig&gt;
        &lt;ItemName&gt;ItemName2&lt;/ItemName&gt;
        &lt;Interval&gt;600&lt;/Interval&gt;
        &lt;/ItemConfig&gt;
        &lt;/AllItemsConfig&gt;</ItemXmlAttributes>
</Instance>
```

Escaped tags and tags within `CDATA` sections are treated equivalently in the XPath data model. If the string is actually a CDATA section, or if you prefer to generate a CDATA section as output, you won't need a template for the escaped tags and can replace the last three templates for these two:

```
<xsl:template match="ItemXmlAttributes">
    <xsl:variable name="input">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="document(concat('data:text/xml,',$input))/AllItemsConfig" />
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Interval[../ItemName='ItemName2']">
    <xsl:copy>600</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

which will generate the `<ItemXmlAttributes>` element as:

```
<ItemXmlAttributes>
    <![CDATA[<AllItemsConfig>
       <ItemConfig>
          <ItemName>ItemName1</ItemName>
          <Interval>200</Interval>
       </ItemConfig>
       <ItemConfig>
          <ItemName>ItemName2</ItemName>
          <Interval>600</Interval>
       </ItemConfig>
    </AllItemsConfig>]]>
</ItemXmlAttributes>
```

which is equivalent (in the XPath data model) to the one with the escaped tags.

Comment: I wasn't actually aware that the data: URI scheme worked with Saxon: thanks for the info. It only works if/because the XML parser recognizes it, so for reference, it might vary depending on which XML parser you are using with Saxon.

Comment: That's right @MichaelKay. It worked in my command line environment (which was configured by the Oxygen XML package), but it didn't work on any online services, nor using the Java 8 TraX API with default parsers. I'm now trying to discover why it works in one and not the other (since I thought they were both using the same parser).

Comment: Perhaps oXygen supplies its own URIResolver which customizes the way URIs passed to the document() function are resolved, so it's oXygen supplying the magic rather than Saxon or the XML parser.